# Visual Studio builds are very slow on 12th gen Intel, and speed drops even more when I minimize it

Tags: visual-studio

I've recently updated my PC (about 4 months ago) from 4th gen i7 to 12th gen i7 (12700K).

What I've expected to happen was that builds would become faster and not slower, and that the builds would at least keep the constant speed when minimized - but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Is there any option I have to enable for VS not to become a 'background task' and thus drop build speed to 10-15% of initial; is there any option I have to enable for it to utilize performance cores at all?

Comment: Simple naive suggestion: did you tried to set the OS governor to performance? I expect the OS not to use only energy-efficient cores when it can, but all cores with this governor. Many applications are not designed for big-little processors and this is not going to change quickly since such processor architecture make (efficient) parallelisation significantly more complex than it currently is (ie. already too complex). That being said, power-efficient cores of AlderLake should not be so slow for such a task as long as they run at the full frequency (certainly no more than 2x slower).

Comment: AFAIK, you can disable the efficient cores in the BIOS. It might seems stupid, but if you have a classic PC (not a notebook), then you should not care much about the power usage. This solution enables applications to use AVX-512 (not available on energy-efficient cores) and do not have any load-balancing issue due to the big-little architecture (there is still the turbo but it is generally fine for that).

Comment: The OS governor is set to performance - yes. I would rather not disable efficiency cores though.